# How Should i import the Model Class on django to other py file to use it?

Tags: django, django-models

I wanted to insert model instance to database from a file. Ι wrote a python program to do so by importing models  but every time Ι get this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'exams'
```

I have tried putting the file in the same folder but then I got:

```
"Relative import error"
```

the expected result was to save model instance in the database.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include more details, at least your files' paths. But if we assume that both `models.py` and I guess `views.py` files are in the same folder you should use:

```
from .models import exams
```

Unless what you are trying to import is the django models. In that case you use:

```
from django.db import models
```

As I said your questiong is poorly written and needs improvement to better understand your problem.